# VelocityJS stepped easing doesn't seem to work anymore?

Tags: javascript, animation, velocity.js

According to VelocityJS's documentation, `el.velocity({ width: 500 }, [ 3 ]);` should animate the width property of `el` from it's native value to 500px over three distinct frames.

However, it appears to just do linear easing instead.

Here's a fiddle with a simplified example:
https://jsfiddle.net/51ovg8wh/7/

Am I missing something obvious or is this just kind of broken?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug - can you open an issue on https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues and when filling in the form link to that fiddle :-)